# python xdata and ydata must be the same length

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, mutex

I think this is an interesting problem. I'd like to read in data from a server so that I can plot data live using matplotlib. Currently I'm testing values that would be read in by simulating using `random`, and I've found that I'm getting this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/lines.py", line 632, in recache
    raise RuntimeError('xdata and ydata must be the same length')
RuntimeError: xdata and ydata must be the same length
```

What I don't understand is how the size of `xdata` and `ydata` could possibly mismatch if I'm using a mutex to protect the data from being read and updated at the same time. You can take a look at the **seriously simple** code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
from threading import Thread, Lock
import random

data = []
mutex = Lock()

# This just simulates reading from a socket.
def data_listener():
    while True:
        with mutex:
            data.append(random.random())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thread(target=data_listener)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    # initialize figure
    plt.figure()
    ln, = plt.plot([])
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 1])
    while True:
        plt.pause(0.1)
        with mutex:
            ln.set_xdata(range(len(data)))
            ln.set_ydata(data)
        plt.draw()
```

As you can see, I am assuring that when appending to the data or adding data to update the plot, you must acquire the mutex, which means `len(xdata)==len(ydata)`. Any ideas with where I've made an assumption would be helpful.

You can copy and run the code yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One first remark: You don't need `plt.draw()`if you use `plt.pause()` as the latter calls the former anyways.

Now if I modify the script like the following, "error" gets never printed, so it seems to run fine.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from threading import Thread, Lock
import random

data = []
mutex = Lock()

# This just simulates reading from a socket.
def data_listener():
    while True:
        with mutex:
            data.append(random.random())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thread(target=data_listener)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    # initialize figure
    plt.figure()
    ln, = plt.plot([])
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    plt.axis([0, 100, 0, 1])
    while True:
        with mutex:
            try:
                ln.set_xdata(range(len(data)))
                ln.set_ydata(data)
                plt.gca().set_xlim(len(data)-60,len(data) )
                plt.pause(0.1)
            except:
                print ("error")
```

Comment: How would I update the plot's x and y axes to give a full view of all the data? I tried `plt.gca().set_xlim(data[:, 0].min() - 0.5, data[:, 0].max() + 0.5)` but this caused me to run into error

Comment: Since the xaxis shows successive integers, I would guess that you need `plt.gca().set_xlim(0, len(data))`.

Comment: I tried this, oddly you get a screen that is completely filled blue with the marker

Comment: Sure, that is expected since in the time it takes the plot to draw, `data_listener` will already have produced some 10000 points or so, much too many to still see a line.

Comment: yes, I threw in `time.sleep(0.001)` in the listener to allow myself to visualize in real time